# Netbeans Nodes API - delete node from explorer

Tags: java, nodes, netbeans-platform

I am using Netbeans [Nodes API](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-nodesapi2.html) to create an explorer in my desktop application (based on Netbeans RCP). The nodes have some hierarchy and when deleting one of them, I also delete all its children. I am experiencing some very strange behavior when removing nodes from this explorer.

Problem: I store the nodes in Cache (which is basically a HashMap) in order to access them easily. When I create a node and delete it in the same session, it disappears from the explorer (this is what I want). However, when I delete the node in different session (I create a node, close the application and restart it again and I want to delete it now), the node stays in the explorer (at least visually, if I try to delete it again, the application says it is not there). I spent couple of hours trying to find out why is this happening and I am clueless.

All the nodes are AbstractNodes:

```
public class ProductNode extends AbstractNode {
...
}
```

Deleting the node:

```
public static void deleteProduct(Product product) {

            String pID = product.getID();

            // get node from cache
            // THIS ALWAYS RETURNS THE CORRECT NODE, never null so the problem is not here
            ProductNode childNode = NDNodesCache.getProductNode(pID);

            // get parent node from cache and remove child node
            // ALSO RETURNS CORRECT NODE
            TopProductNode parent = NDNodesCache.getTopProductNode();
            parent.getChildren().remove(new Node[]{childNode});

            // remove the node from node cache
            NDNodesCache.removeProductNode(pID);
    }
```

After calling this function, the node cannot be deleted again since the application claims it is not there but is stays there visually (and even provide a context menu associated with that node).

First I thought that there is something wrong with the cache but it always return the desired node, no matter when (even after application is relaunched since the nodes are added there during initialization of explorer). Do you have any idea how to fix this?

I also tried calling `childNode.destroy();` This changes the appearance of the node but does not remove it completely.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the following piece of code that I've made;
https://github.com/flinkgutt/netbeans-samples/blob/master/nodes/node-samples/view-beantree/src/net/flinkgutt/samples/nodes/view/beantree/CategoryNode.java
At the bottom of the file there is a private class called "RemoveCategoryAction" that should help you on your way.

The entire project is mostly to show how to do certain things with Nodes, deleting nodes amongst them. The private class is called from a context menu on the node in the beantreeview.

Hope it helps!